# Transforming letters into 0 in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am a very beginner in Python Pandas.
I have a Data set with wrongly types postal codes : last characters are random letters.
How can I transform these letters into 0 ?

I tried this but obviously the whole postal code turns out to a 0 :

if data["CODE_POSTAL_PATIENT"].str.isalpha:

df1 = data["CODE_POSTAL_PATIENT"].transform(lambda x: 0)

Thanks in advance !

Comment: please provide a sample of the data and the matching output

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have zip codes like '12XY#' and want to change to '12000', use a regex to match the non digits and replace them with "0" using [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df['CODE_POSTAL_CORRECTED'] = df['CODE_POSTAL'].str.replace('\D', '0', regex=True)
```

output:

```
  CODE_POSTAL CODE_POSTAL_CORRECTED
0       12345                 12345
1       12XY#                 12000
```

regex:

```
\D    # match a non digit
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'CODE_POSTAL_PATIENT': ['abcdr', 'efghr']})
df['0'] = ['0' for i in range(len(df))]
df['new'] = df['CODE_POSTAL_PATIENT'].str[:-1]+df['0']
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Replace everything except digits

```
df['CODE_POSTAL'].str.replace('[^\d]','0',regex=True)
```